# Обращение к принтеру через python

Tags: python, принтер

Как заставить принтер печатать картинку через python? Причем не открывать окно с выбором копий и прочих настроек, а сразу печатал.

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: related [Print to standard printer from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12723818/4279)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821817/201445