# Использование принтера в python

Tags: python, принтер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызвать окно печати документа через python. И возможно ли таким образом печатать не только текст, но и картинки?

Comment: Не знаю насчет конкретных библиотек для печати, но можно через библиотеку Qt это сделать. Например, через pyqt5

Comment: пример для gtk: [How to add a print dialog to an application](https://askubuntu.com/q/220350/3712)

Answer (score 2):

В `Qt` можно печатать через виджеты, тут [привожу пример печати](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/32ca9d1ce0f12069300e02127d6ac4384f059e47/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/printer__QTextEdit__QPrinter__QPrinterDialog) содержимого редактора [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html). При запуске будет открыт [диалог печати](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QPrintDialog.html):

```
# pip install PyQt5
from PyQt5 import Qt


# https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/5909792
html = """
<p>Red dot:</p><br>
<img width="100" src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    printer = Qt.QPrinter()

    te = Qt.QTextEdit()
    te.setHtml(html)
    te.show()

    print_dialog = Qt.QPrintDialog(printer)
    if print_dialog.exec() == Qt.QDialog.Accepted:
        te.print(printer)

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Класс [QPrinter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QPrinter.html) умеет печатать в PDF, для этого [нужно указывать путь](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/7529051c8c40c7fcad0e5f9f4d6e7de2e3471145/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/printer_to_PDF__QTextEdit__QPrinter__QPrinterDialog/main.py) с расширением `pdf` через метод [setOutputFileName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setOutputFileName):

```
printer.setOutputFileName('result.pdf')
te.print(printer)
```

[Результат](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/7529051c8c40c7fcad0e5f9f4d6e7de2e3471145/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/printer_to_PDF__QTextEdit__QPrinter__QPrinterDialog/result.pdf):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]